# Bind to tile and toast, Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, azure

My lecturer told me that you cannot bind to toast and tile push notifications when working with Windows Phone.

For example...

```
channel.BindToShellTile();
channel.BindToShellToast();
```

although when I do the above, it works fine. What I was told is that eventually either the Mobile app or cloud service will fail.

Can anyone shed some light on this please, I cannot find any documentation that says I cannot do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can ask your lecturer why he told you so :)

Comment: yes, but I would like to know now as it is bugging me :-)

Comment: well it is in Microsoft.Phone.Notification namespace. namespace says itself it belongs to windows phone. so i think your lecturer is a bit confused or he talked about something else

Comment: thanks, I will discuss this with him, think he got confused.